# What is the most computationally efficient Turing complete system?

Tags: optimization, efficiency, turing-completeness

I'm making a program that involves making models of and working with arbitrary systems (or programs). What is the most computationally efficient Turing complete system to model these in?

By "arbitrary system", I mean anything with inputs and outputs. It could be anything from a function that adds 1 to the input to a complicated video game.

What is the most computationally efficient (or fastest) Turing complete system to simulate these arbitrary systems in?

For example, if you were to simulate any program as a test (for example, a 4-bit adder) in some Turing complete system, what system would result in that test program getting simulated the fastest?

User D.W. suggested using asymptotic worst-case runtime as the metric for evaluating the different systems' computational efficiency.

Comment: I think you're going to have to expand on what you mean.  How do you measure the computational efficiency of a system?  It's not clear what you mean by "arbitrary systems" (what kinds of systems?) or by "making models of them" (what do you want to do with these models?  what capabilities do you want to have?)  What approaches have you considered?

Comment: @D.W. I've edited the question, thanks

Comment: Thanks for answering some of the questions I raised.  However, I think we need clarity on them all.  I still don't understand what you mean by "computationally efficient" or how you will evaluate proposed answers.  I suggest you define the metrics you use to evaluate answers.  It might also help to share with us what approaches you've considered and how you evaluate them (how computationally efficient do you consider they are?)

Comment: @D.W. I've edited the question again. The metric is just the speed at which the model is simulated. I don't know where to begin with finding the most efficient Turing complete system, so I haven't considered any approaches yet. 

For clarity: to find how "computationally efficient" a Turing complete system is, write any program and check how fast it runs compared to the same program in any other system.

Comment: I don't really understand the question.  Suppose I was considering "Turing machines" or "word-RAM machines" as my two candidate systems.  How would I measure which one is more computationally efficient?

Comment: To find which one is more computationally efficient (or, faster), write a program to simulate both Turing complete systems. Then choose any test program (for example, a 4-bit adder) and write that test program in both systems. Whichever Turing complete system runs the test program the fastest is the more computationally efficient Turing complete system.

Comment: I suggest [edit]ing the question to clarify that in the question.  I'm concerned the answer might depend on what particular program I use to simulate a Turing machine and what particular program I use to simulate a word-RAM machine and what computer I run the program on, so I'm trying to puzzle through whether the metric can be made well-defined.  Perhaps you care about asymptotic worst-case runtime for the algorithm with the best worst-case runtime?

Comment: Edited again. As for the result depending on what computer the systems are run on, can't you just (theoretically) use the same computer for both?

Comment: Sure, but if you run both on computer A, maybe one system is faster, and if you run both on computer B, maybe the other system is faster.

Comment: Can that actually happen? Even if it can, I don't really care too much if what I get is only usually the fastest system. A good enough answer to my question would suffice.